# Sort a list, but leave a specified value in place

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I need to use the `numpy.argsort` function (or a code that makes the same) but ignoring a concrete value, for example *-1*, and keeping it in the resulted array

If this is the list: [5,8,1,-1,2,4], I need a result like [3,4,0,-1,1,2]

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't understand your definition of a "concrete value"

Comment: Have you tried to stored it, replace it with `-np.inf`, and change it back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locate and remove each of the values to ignore, remembering their positions.  For instance, in this case, you might store the index and value as `ignore = (3, -1)`.

Sort the remaining list as usual.

Reinsert the missing element: `mylist.insert(ignore[0], ignore[1])`

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Thanks a lot Prune, it works with your idea. Here a very naive implementation:

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist=[5,8,1,-1,2,4]
print 'mylist: ',mylist
ignored=[]
new_my_list=[]

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i]==-1:
        ignored.append((i,mylist[i]))
    else:
        new_my_list.append(mylist[i])

print 'new_my_list without -1: ',new_my_list

mylist_sorted=list(np.argsort(new_my_list))

print 'mylist_sorted: ',mylist_sorted

temp_orders=list(np.zeros(len(mylist_sorted)))
for fr in range(len(mylist_sorted)):
            idx=mylist_sorted[fr]
            temp_orders[idx]=fr

print 'temp_orders: ',temp_orders

for ig in range(len(ignored)):
    ig_add=ignored[ig]
    temp_orders.insert(ig_add[0], ig_add[1])

print 'new_my_list with -1: ',temp_orders
```

---

One improvement to the last loop:

```
for ig_idx, ig_value in ignored):
    temp_orders.insert(ig_idx, ig_val)
```

Comment: You did a good job of working your way through that!
I suggest that you come back to this code once in a while as you learn more Python, to see what you might improve.  I added one.